# Bash script to change filename

Tags: regex, bash

I have files with this format: `ddmmyyyyRANDOM.mp3`

and i want to rename them in: `yyyy-mm-dd-RANDOM.mp3`

`RANDOM` is a random string which can include spaces. 
not a homework question. I am struck here and i tried various regex but coudnt find out. I need to write bash script

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161987/74329

Comment: have a look at the perl `rename` utility that has all the beautiful  power of perl-regexps!

Answer (score 2):

I would break in parts by method of substring

```
 filename="ddmmyyyyRANDOM.mp3"
part1=${filename:0:8} #this should get you ddmmyyy
part2=${filename:9:6} #this should get you RANDOM
filenamenew=$part1$part2".mp3"
mv $fileneme $filenamenew
```

RUN in a loop if you have more than 1 filename

Comment: `RANDOM` is well, a random not non-fixed-length string to subscripting doesn't work here

Comment: Well if you get the length of the string at start then its possible

Comment: Random part would be total length - 8 - 4 (-4 because .mp3 is 4 letters)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FILE="23022014hello world.mp3"
mv "$FILE" "$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\3-\2-\1-\4/')"
```

It cuts the first 2 numbers, second 2 numbers, next 4 numbers and remaining characters separately and arranges according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for file in *; do
    new=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})(.*)$/\3-\2-\1-\4/')
    mv "$file" "$new" 
done
```

more about regex [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/hN9cZ0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rename` utility

```
touch 12021960RANDOM.mp3 "01041973 random with spaces.mp3"

$ rename -n 's/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/$3-$2-$1-/' *.mp3
01041973 random with spaces.mp3 renamed as 1973-04-01- random with spaces.mp3
12021960RANDOM.mp3 renamed as 1960-02-12-RANDOM.mp3
```

When you're happy with the output, remove the `-n` part to actually perform the rename